# Getting Lat/Long Out Of Parse PFGeoPoint

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, geopoints

I currently have a PFGeoPoint on a Parse Server which I can successfully retrieve by doing the following (in Swift):

```
let geo = listingObject?.objectForKey("geo")
// <PFGeoPoint: 0x7ff37d184840, latitude: 51.510005, longitude: -0.128493>
```

What I am now wanting to do is get the latitude and longitude out of this into their own variables.

When I create a map annotation for example the following works:

```
let anno = mapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (geo?.latitude)!, longitude: (geo?.longitude)!))
```

However this produces an error:

```
let latitude = geo?.latitude
// Ambiguous use of 'latitude'
```

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 2):

`objectForKey` returns `AnyObject`, the compiler doesn't know that the type is `PFGeoPoint`. The solution is to cast the value to the proper type.

And when using optional bindings you can get rid of all `?!` marks

```
if let geo = listingObject?.objectForKey("geo") as? PFGeoPoint {
    let anno = mapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: geo.latitude, longitude: geo.longitude)
}
```